# Determine if a supplier supplies all products in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `SupplierCatalog (idProduct, idSupplier)`. A product can be supplied by multiple suppliers; and a supplier supplies multiple products (many-to-many relation).

I want to check if a supplier supplies all products in a list, for example, the products to check are `(10, 26, 40, 42, 50)` and the supplier is `5`.

I tried:

```sql
SELECT idproduct 
FROM SupplierCatalog 
where idProduct IN (10, 26, 40, 42, 50) AND idSupplier = 5
```

and then check in C# if number of rows returned equal the number of products passed in the query, it works but it doesn't look professional to me.

Does anyone have a clue on how to obtain the result I want, I just one a `TRUE` if all match or `FALSE` if at least one didn't match.

Comment: Please work on the grammar. It will help get answers quicker.

Comment: i'll try my best my apologies

Comment: Thank you @Salman, i have seen that answer before writing my question, i just want to know if there is a way to know if all match without giving the number of values to check.

Comment: @Mila Depends on where the list is coming from. If you are building it through code then it is convenient to add the number at the same time. If it is from a sub-query then you can match the `COUNT`s.

Comment: You are totally right, thank you again ^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that `idProduct, idSupplier` are unique*, here is a simple query:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM SupplierCatalog
WHERE idProduct IN (10, 26, 40, 42, 50) AND idSupplier = 5
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5 -- this is the number of items in the above list
```

This returns 0 or 1 rows which is all you need to check in your code.

<sub>* If duplicates are allowed/present change to `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idProduct) ...`</sub>

Answer (score 7):

```sql
SELECT idproduct 
  FROM SupplierCatalog 
 WHERE idProduct IN (10, 26, 40, 42, 50) 
   AND idSupplier = 5 
 GROUP BY idproduct 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
```

0 rows is false and 1 row is true

You can remove the `AND idSupplier = 5` and get all the suppliers